# get list of nodes in xml file, when the xpath is known partially

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I have this xml file:

```
<root>
    <products>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>newProduct</name>
    </products>
    <cars>
        <car>
            <id>qw123</id>
            <color>red</color>
        </car>
        <car>
            <id>AS6789</id>
            <color>blue</color>
        </car>
    </cars>
</root>
```

I need to extract in a list all the elements with the tag "id" and which are included in the tag "cars", using a Java method. The method I created is:

```
    private static List<Node> searchNodes(Document doc, String nodeName, String tag) {

    Node mainNode = doc.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0);  
    List<Node> result = new ArrayList<Node>();

    NodeList list = mainNode.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = list.item(i);
        if (node.getNodeName().equals(nodeName)) {
            result.add(node);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works only if the "id" is a direct child of "cars". So, in this case, works if "tag" is "products".

Comment: Smells like homework... show us what you did try to solve the problem.

Comment: OK, I'll add my code.

Comment: Doesn't look XPath related? (Using XPath would certainly help to solve the problem, but there is no trace of it in your code.)

Answer (score 0):

Found. I am not sure if it is the best solution, but at least it worked:

```
    private static List<Node> searchNodes(Document doc, String nodeName, String tag) {
    Node mainNode = doc.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0);  
    List<Node> result = new ArrayList<Node>(); 

    NodeList list = mainNode.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = list.item(i);
        if (node.getNodeName().equals(nodeName)) {
            result.add(node);
        } else {
            result.addAll(getChilds(node, nodeName));
        }
    }
    return result;      
}

private static List<Node> getChilds(Node node, String nodeName) {
    NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
    List<Node> result = new ArrayList<Node>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        if (list.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodeName)) {
            result.add(list.item(i));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```